# Prove $\exists x$ st $\|x\|=1$ and $\operatorname{dist}(x,Y)=1$

Tags: functional-analysis

> If $Y$ be a  finite-dimensional proper subspace of a normed linear space $X$, then show that there exists $x\in X$ st $\|x\|=1$ and $\operatorname{dist}(x,Y)=1$

For any $x \in X$ st $\|x\|=1$ we have $\operatorname{dist}(x,Y)\le 1$ since $0\in Y$, so we need to show there exists a point $x\in X$ with $\|x\|=1$ and $\operatorname{dist}(x,Y)\ge 1$ that will complete the proof.

Comment: Fix an $x_0 \in X\setminus Y$ and look at $Z = Y \oplus \mathbb{R}\cdot x_0$ (or replace $\mathbb{R}$ with $\mathbb{C}$ if you consider complex scalars).

Comment: What is $Z = Y \oplus \mathbb{R}\cdot x_0$?

Comment: Or, take the span, $Z$, of $Y\cup x_0$. Use Riesz's Lemma (see Remark 1, [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%27s_lemma)).

Comment: It's the subspace of $X$ spanned by $Y$ and $x_0$, the direct sum of the two subspaces $Y$ and $\mathbb{R}\cdot x_0$.

Comment: @DavidMitra But that remark is for finite dimensional $X$, here $Y$, the subspace is finite dimensional and can you please explain proof of that remark.

Comment: You apply the result to $Z$ and $Y$.

Comment: As for the proof: the continuous function ${\rm dist\,}(x_0,Y)$ achieves its maximum value on the unit sphere of $Z$. By Riesz's Lemma, this value is $1$.

Comment: @DavidMitra I do not understand why is this value 1?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to write "the function $d(x)={\rm dist\,}(x, Y)$ on $Z$". By Riesz,  given $0<\alpha<1$, there is an $x $ in the unit sphere of $Z$ with $\Vert x-y\Vert>\alpha$ for all $y\in Y$; for this $x$, $d(x)\ge \alpha$. So the  max of $d$ on the unit sphere of $Z$ has to be $1$.

Comment: So $d$ will achieve the value $\alpha$ at some $x_0$ i.e. $d(x_0)=\alpha$ and since $\alpha<1$ we can say that $d(x_0)<1$ but why max of $d$ has to be 1?

Comment: Because $\alpha$ was an arbitrary positive number less than $1$. For any $\alpha<1$, we know ${\rm max\,} d\ge \alpha$. Of course, $d\le 1$ always, so the max is $1$. (You can prove your result without using Riesz. Let $a=d(x_0, Y)\ne0$. Then $1= d(x_0/a,Y)$. Choose $y_n\in Y$ with $\Vert y_n -x_0/d\Vert\rightarrow 1$. Let $y$ be a limit point of $(y_n)$. Show that $y-x_0/d$ is the element of $B(X)$ you're looking for.)

Comment: This is what's done, I think, in the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First** show that **for any $x\in X$, $\exists y_0\in Y:\|x-y_0\|=\text{dist}(x,Y)$.**

For this, let $a=\text{dist}(x,Y)$. So there is a sequence $\{y_n\}\in Y$ such that $\|x-y_n\|\le a+\frac{1}{n}$. So $y_n$ is a bounded sequence in $Y$. Let $\|y_n\|\le M$ (say), for all $n$. Hence the subset $A=\{y\in Y:\|y\| \le M\}$ is a closed and bounded subset of the finite dimensional subspace $Y$ and hence $A$ is compact. So $y_n$ has a convergent subsequence, say $y_{n_k}\to y_0$ in $A$. Now $\|x-y_0\|\ge \text{dist}(x,Y)=a$ and $\|x-y_0\|\le \|x-y_{n_k}\|+\|y_{n_k}-y_0\|\le a+ \frac{1}{n_k}+\|y_{n_k}-y_0\|$, for all $k$. Hence taking limit, $a\le \|x-y_0\|\le a$ i.e. $\|x-y_0\|=a=\text{dist}(x,Y)$.

**For the remaining part,** proceed as follows:

Let $v\in X\setminus Y$ and let $b=\text{dist}(v,Y)$. Clearly $b>0$ as $Y$ (being finite dimensional) is closed. By the first part, we have $\exists y_0\in Y$ such that $b=\|v-y_0\|$. So choose $x=c(v-y_0)$, where $c=\frac{1}{\|v-y_0\|}=\frac{1}{b}$. Clearly $\|x\|=1$ and for any $y\in Y$,
$$\|x-y\|=\|c(v-y_0)-y\|=c\|v-y_0-c^{-1}y\|=c\|v-y_1\|,$$
where $y_1=y_0+c^{-1}y\in Y$. Hence $\|x-y\|\ge c \cdot \text{dist}(v,Y)=cb=1$. Hence $\text{dist}(x,Y)\ge 1$ as required.